How to customize MUI AutoComplete component to support sub-menu options?
I am using MUI AutoComplete to display the list of options. But, some of them need to have sub-menu kind of options. I am not able to implement it. Below is what I was able to implement so far. But, it doesn't work when I select the different options from sub-menu options. For example, it works if I select any options. If I have initially selected label410 (Entry) and then select label410) Exit, it doesn't work anymore. onChange event doesn't get executed. But, if I close the dropdown and re-open, it displays the correct option.
Here is my implementation so far. Everything is simple. I am only passing the prop renderOptio to display the submenus. Here is the component
const OptionItem = ({
  props: { className, ...props },
  option,
  shapeId,
  state: { selected },
  selectedCategoryId,
}: OptionItemProps) => {

  const [isCategoriesOpen, setIsCategoriesOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const hanleDisplayCategories = () => {
    if (option.categories) {
      setIsCategoriesOpen(!isCategoriesOpen);
    }
  };

  const handleSelectLabelOrCategory = (categoryId?: string) => {
       // update the value here
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        onClick={() =>
          option.categories
            ? hanleDisplayCategories()
            : handleSelectLabelOrCategory()
        }
      >
        <MenuItem
          sx={{
            width: '100%',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
          selected={!option.categories && selected}
          {...(!option.categories ? props : {})}
        >
          <Typography>{option.name}</Typography>
          {option.categories && <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
        </MenuItem>
      </Box>
      {option.categories && (
        <Collapse in={isCategoriesOpen}>
          <List sx={{ pl: 3 }}>
            {option.categories.map((category) => (
              <Box
                key={category.id}
                onClick={() => handleSelectLabelOrCategory(category.id)}
              >
                <MenuItem
                  {...props}
                  selected={category.id === selectedCategoryId && selected}
                >
                  <Typography>{category.name}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              </Box>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

I am completely open to use other alternatives as well. As long as I can implement sub-menus and display the selected item.


I hope you do not have to select the item which has submenus. You only need to select the submenu items in that case. Check this autocomplete if it solves your problem.
